# Read DataAnnotations from a collection of models in an MCV2 view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, view, data-annotations

In my MVC2 AdminArea I'd like to create an overview table for each of my domain models. 
I am using DataAnnotations like the following for the properties of those domain model objects:

```
[DisplayName("MyPropertyName")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Now my question is: How can I access the DisplayName Attribute if my view receives a collection of my domain models? I need this to build the table headers which are defined outside of the usual

```
<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
```

loop. Inside this loop I can write

```
<%: Html.LabelFor(c => item.Name) %>
```

but is there any way to access this information using the collection of items instead of a concrete instance?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your model stongly typed, like `List<Product>`?

Comment: Yes, it is an IEnumerable<Product>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `ModelMetaData` class that has a static method called `FromLambdaExpression`.  If you call it and pass in your property, along with your `ViewData`, it will return an instance of `ModelMetaData`.  That class has a `DisplayName` property that should give you what you need.  You can also get other meta data information from this object.

For example, you can create an empty `ViewDataDictionary` object to get this information.  It can be empty because the `ModelMetaData` doesn't actually use the instance, it just needs the generic class to define the type being used.

```
//This would typically be just your view model data.    
ViewDataDictionary<IEnumerable<Person>> data = new ViewDataDictionary<IEnumerable<Person>>();

ModelMetadata result = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(p => p.First().Name, data);
string displayName = result.DisplayName;
```

The `First()` method call doesn't break even if you have no actual `Person` object because the lambda is simply trying to find the property you want the meta data about.  Similarly, you could d this for a single `Person` object:

```
//This would typically be just your view model data.    
ViewDataDictionary<Person> data = new ViewDataDictionary<Person>();

ModelMetadata result = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(p => p.Name, data);
```

You could clean this up significantly with a helper or extension method, but this should put you on the right path.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This works fine but I wonder if I can do this automatically for a set of model properties (can I somehow iterate over all properties?). I don't want to create a dictionary with all DisplayNames that I want to show in my view.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I followed sgriffinusa's advise (thanks again!) and created a strongly typed HtmlHelper:

```
public static MvcHtmlString MetaDisplayName<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression) where TModel : class
{
    ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData);
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(metadata.GetDisplayName());
}
```

Of course TModel still is a **collection** of domain models like stated in my inital question but we can call the helper in the view like this:

```
<%: Html.MetaDisplayName(p => p.First().Name) %>
```